# Finding an equivalent for pdIdent (nlme-Package) for the lmer-function (lme4-Package)

Tags: r, covariance, lme4, mixed-models, variance

I am wondering whether it is possible to "translate" a simple mixed-models analysis using the function `lme` (package nlme) with a `pdIdent`-line to an equivalent analysis for the `lmer` (package lme4).

In short, I am looking for a simple copy of the following analysis using the `lmer`-function. The data is from another example in the net:

```
library(nlme)

Q <- factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2))
R <- factor(c(1, 1 , 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3))
y <- c(51.43, 51.28, 50.93, 50.75, 50.47, 50.83, 51.91, 52.43, 52.26, 52.33, 51.58, 51.23)
DS <- data.frame(Q, R, y)
DS$Q <- as.factor(DS$Q)
DS$R <- as.factor(DS$R)


lme3 <- lme(y ~ Q, random = list(R = pdIdent(~ Q - 1)), data = DS)
summary(lme3)
```

and this yields variances of `0.3979` for `Q1` and `Q2`

```
Random effects:
 Formula: ~Q - 1 | R
 Structure: Multiple of an Identity
               Q1        Q2  Residual
StdDev: 0.3979283 0.3979283 0.2202835
```

on a 2x3 matrix. The random effect are

```
> ranef(lme3)
           Q1         Q2
1  0.35263487  0.1849888
2 -0.09393962  0.2933806
3 -0.25869525 -0.4783694
```

I am aware that in `lmer` one gets close by specifing a random intercept for the `Q:R`-Interaction

```
lmer3 <- lmer(y ~ Q + (-1 + 1 | Q:R), data = DS)
summary(lmer3)
```

which yields a variance for the interaction term equal to the lme calculations

```
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Q:R      (Intercept) 0.15835  0.3979  
 Residual             0.04852  0.2203  
Number of obs: 12, groups:  Q:R, 6
```

and an 1x6 random effects matrix:

```
$`Q:R`
    (Intercept)
1:1  0.35263436
1:2 -0.09393948
1:3 -0.25869488
2:1  0.18498852
2:2  0.29338022
2:3 -0.47836874

with conditional variances for “Q:R”
```

However, I am not quite sure whether the two models are the same as for example one has to check twice normality of random effect in the first model, but only once in the second. So, any suggestions to these results and to improve the copy? Maybe using a dummy-variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to confirm that two models are equivalent is to compare the log-likelihoods:

```r
> logLik(lme3)
'log Lik.' -4.889587 (df=4)
> logLik(lmer3)
'log Lik.' -4.889587 (df=4)
```

Roughly speaking, this is a *sufficient* condition to consider the two models the same. (However, different packages may drop parameter-independent constants from log-likelihoods, so you may get different log-likelihoods from different packages even for equivalent models ...)

You'll also get an equivalent model this way:

```r
DS <- transform(DS, QR = interaction(Q,R))
summary(lme(y~Q, random = ~1|QR, data = DS))
```

Finally, it's not clear what your `-1 + 1` is doing in your `lmer` call: `y ~ Q + (1 | Q:R)` should work fine.

Comment: Hi Ben Bolker, thanks a lot for the explanations. And you are right, the -1 + 1 is a coding error, the -1 can be omitted.